# How to write a regex in Python with named groups to match this?

Tags: python, regex, regex-group

I have a file which would contain the following lines.

comm=adbd pid=11108 prio=120 success=1 target_cpu=001

I have written the following regex to match.

```
_sched_wakeup_pattern = re.compile(r"""
comm=(?P<next_comm>.+?)
\spid=(?P<next_pid>\d+)
\sprio=(?P<next_prio>\d+)
\ssuccess=(?P<success>\d)
\starget_cpu=(?P<target_cpu>\d+)
""", re.VERBOSE)
```

But now I've lines like the following also where the success component isn't there.

comm=rcu_preempt pid=7 prio=120 target_cpu=007

How do I modify my regex here to match both the cases? I tried by putting a * everywhere in that line containing "success", but it throws errors.

Comment: can you show some part of content of that file?

Comment: It would be like this
comm=rcu_preempt pid=7 prio=120 target_cpu=007
comm=kworker/u16:2 pid=73 prio=120 target_cpu=006
comm=kworker/u16:4 pid=364 prio=120 target_cpu=005

Or

comm=adbd pid=11108 prio=120 success=1 target_cpu=001
comm=kworker/1:1 pid=16625 prio=120 success=1 target_cpu=001
comm=rcu_preempt pid=7 prio=120 success=1 target_cpu=002

I want a common one regex which can be used for both purposes

Comment: Every line start with comm. Not able to paste as it is in the file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution using a regex *non-capturing group* and the `regex.findall` function:

```
import regex
...
fh = open('lines.txt', 'r');  // considering 'lines.txt' is your initial file
commlines = fh.read()

_sched_wakeup_pattern = regex.compile(r"""
comm=(?P<next_comm>[\S]+?)
\spid=(?P<next_pid>\d+)
\sprio=(?P<next_prio>\d+)
(?:\ssuccess=)?(?P<success>\d)?
\starget_cpu=(?P<target_cpu>\d+)
""", regex.VERBOSE)

result = regex.findall(_sched_wakeup_pattern, commlines)

template = "{0:15}|{1:10}|{2:9}|{3:7}|{4:10}" # column widths
print(template.format("next_comm", "next_pid", "next_prio", "success", "target_cpu")) # header

for t in result:
    print(template.format(*t))
```

**Beautified** output:

```
next_comm      |next_pid  |next_prio|success|target_cpu
rcu_preempt    |7         |120      |       |007       
kworker/u16:2  |73        |120      |       |006       
kworker/u16:4  |364       |120      |       |005       
adbd           |11108     |120      |1      |001       
kworker/1:1    |16625     |120      |1      |001       
rcu_preempt    |7         |120      |1      |002
```

Answer (score 2):

Matching `0` or `1` repetitions do  `(your_string)?`.

```
_sched_wakeup_pattern = re.compile(r"""
comm=(?P<next_comm>.+?)
\spid=(?P<next_pid>\d+)
\sprio=(?P<next_prio>\d+)
\s?(success=(?P<success>\d))?
\starget_cpu=(?P<target_cpu>\d+)
""", re.VERBOSE)
```

There you go
Here it looks for the whole string so, it also print `success=`:

```
output =>
('rcu_preempt', '7', '120', '', '', '007')
('kworker/u16:2', '73', '120', '', '', '006')
('kworker/u16:4', '364', '120', '', '', '005')
('adbd', '11108', '120', 'success=1', '1', '001')
('kworker/1:1', '16625', '120', 'success=1', '1', '001')
('rcu_preempt', '7', '120', 'success=1', '1', '002')
```

now we need to figure out a way to remove that `"success="`. That doesn't seem difficult.

[edited]
`(?:\ssuccess=)?(?P<success>\d)?` works just nicely.
by [RomanPerekhrest](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3185459/romanperekhrest)